# Determine a projection of a integral

Tags: inner-products

> Determine the polinomial function p(t) belonging to $\mathbb{R}_2[t]$ so that the value of
>
> $\int_{0}^{2\pi} [p(t)- \cos(t)]^2 dt$
>
> is minimal.

So as this is problem of linear algebra my first thought was to find the projection of the integral in $\mathbb{R}_2[t]$   .

However I need an orthogonal basis for $\mathbb{R}_2[t]$...

But when I tried to do it using Gram-Schmidt process I reach to the vectors $(1,0, -t^2$) and 1 and $-t^2$ are not orthogonal so I must be applying it wrongly...

Can someone plese help finding out this... The fact that we have a integral instead of vectors is making me confused.

Thank you!

Comment: As the integral is always positive... why not just let $p(t)$ be $\cos(t)$ (or its taylor series)?

Comment: $0$ as a base vector sounds weird